# How to calculate length of time before a variable switches?

Tags: r

I have a data from an activity monitor where I need to calculate the length of time asleep vs awake. For each 5 minute time point, I have marked whether or not the subject was asleep vs. awake during that period. I cannot figure out how to calculate how long the animal is continuously asleep before the "state" column switches to awake (aka, if there were two "awake" rows in a row and then the state switched backed to "sleep", I would want R to tell me that the subject was awake for the 8:00-8:05 and 8:05-8:10 period).

Finally, I'd like to then be able to say, in an entire day, what is the average length of time of an awake period vs a sleeping period?

Many thanks!! Example of my df below.

```
timeofday<-c("8:00","8:05","8:10","8:20","8:25")
activity<-c(1250,1650,200,100,40)
state<-c("awake","awake","sleep","sleep","sleep")
data_frame(timeofday,state,activity
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RnPw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of output you are looking for but you can try this approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(timeperiod = hm(timeofday), 
         group = data.table::rleid(state)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(timeofday = paste(first(timeofday), last(timeofday), sep = '-'), 
            state = first(state), 
            timeperiod = last(timeperiod) - first(timeperiod))

#  group timeofday state timeperiod
#  <int> <chr>     <chr> <Period>  
#1     1 8:00-8:05 awake 5M 0S     
#2     2 8:10-8:25 sleep 15M 0S
```

Comment: note that the groups have a 'gap' of 5 minutes here... 8:05 >> 8:10 has no state... Not sure if this is desired by TS, since he/she did not provide desired output.. Just thought it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: this definitely is desired since really the "8:05" interval covers 8:05 to 8:10

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table`approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, timeofday := as.ITime(timeofday)]
# create end times, or else you will get gaps
mydata[, timeofday_2 := shift(timeofday, type = "lead")]
mydata[is.na(timeofday_2), timeofday_2 := timeofday]
# summarise
mydata[, .(state = state[1], 
           from = min(timeofday), 
           to = max(timeofday_2)), 
       by = .(period = rleid(state))]
#    period state     from       to
# 1:      1 awake 08:00:00 08:10:00
# 2:      2 sleep 08:10:00 08:25:00
```

Comment: this is incredible!! however, I need to make sure that i get these periods grouped by each subject for each week of age. So my desired output will look exactly as above, but with each subject's awake and rest states analyzed individually, as well as for each week of age. I would sort these by my columns called "name" and "weeksold". Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Coerce the time vector to appropriate type: timeofday => POSIXlt vector
df$timeofday <- strptime(
  df$timeofday, 
  "%H:%M"
)

# Numericise the state of the animal: state_no => integer vector
df$state_no <- as.integer(
  factor(
    df$state,
    levels = c("awake", "rest", "sleep"),
    ordered = TRUE
  )
)

# Group the patient state: grp => integer vector
df$grp <- with(
  df[order(timeofday),],
  cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(state_no)) > 0))
)

# Split-apply-combine to calculate the start and end times of each 
# event: res => data.frame 
res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df, split(df, grp)), function(x){
        data.frame(
          event = unique(x$grp),
          state = unique(x$state),
          start_time = format(min(x$timeofday, na.rm = TRUE), "%H:%M"),
          end_time = format(max(x$timeofday, na.rm = TRUE), "%H:%M"),
          duration_in_approx_5_mins = difftime(
            max(x$timeofday, na.rm = TRUE),
            min(x$timeofday, na.rm = TRUE),
            units = "mins"
          )
        )  
      }
    )
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = NULL
)

# Print the result: data.frame => stdout(console)
res
```